# Show CoffeeScript Lint on Codemirror

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I was playing with CoffeeScript earlier on Codemirror and I don't know why but linting is not working with Codemirror. Even the lint that's provided with the Codemirror package is not working for me.

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?

```js
// Initialize CodeMirror editor
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  mode: "text/x-coffeescript",
  tabMode: "indent",
  styleActiveLine: true,
  lineNumbers: true,
  lineWrapping: true,
  autoCloseTags: true,
  foldGutter: true,
  dragDrop: true,
  lint: true,
  gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers", "CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"]
})
```

```css
.CodeMirror {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.0.0/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldgutter.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/addon/hint/show-hint.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/addon/lint/lint.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/css/css.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/edit/closetag.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/selection/active-line.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldcode.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldgutter.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/brace-fold.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/xml-fold.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/comment-fold.js"></script>
<script src="http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
<script src="http://coffeelint.org/js/coffeelint.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/coffeescript/coffeescript.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/lint/coffeescript-lint.js"></script>

<textarea id="code">function () {}</textarea>
```

Comment: If there's coffee on the mirror then the mirror won't work as you might expect. I'd recommend downloading Cloth or Rag and use `Cloth.wipe()` or `Rag.spitOn().wipe()`. I hope this helps.

Comment: The coffee mirrors are only what the `coffeescript-lint.js ` file requires. I'm not familiar with Cloth or Rag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#362e030f5d37beb17766999e92ef4e88

Haha funny mistake. I forgot to add `lint.js`.

```
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/lint/lint.js"></script>
```

A quick note for anyone using this. I tried refreshing the lint with `editor.refresh()` to refresh the CodeMirror instance to get CoffeeScript lints instead of JavaScript lints in my editor, but the only way I could get it to work was disabling lints and re-enabling with...

```
editor.setOption("lint", false)
editor.setOption("lint", true)
```

Here's the snippet!

```js
// Initialize CodeMirror editor
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  mode: "text/x-coffeescript",
  tabMode: "indent",
  styleActiveLine: true,
  lineNumbers: true,
  lineWrapping: true,
  autoCloseTags: true,
  foldGutter: true,
  dragDrop: true,
  lint: true,
  gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers", "CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"]
})
```

```css
.CodeMirror {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.0.0/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/addon/lint/lint.css">
<script src="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/lint/lint.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/coffeescript/coffeescript.js"></script>
<script src="http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
<script src="http://coffeelint.org/js/coffeelint.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/lint/coffeescript-lint.js"></script>

<textarea id="code">function () {}
  
# Initialize CodeMirror editor
editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'),
  mode: 'text/x-coffeescript'
  tabMode: 'indent'
  styleActiveLine: true
  lineNumbers: true
  lineWrapping: true
  autoCloseTags: true
  foldGutter: true
  dragDrop: true
  lint: true
  gutters: [
    'CodeMirror-lint-markers'
    'CodeMirror-linenumbers'
    'CodeMirror-foldgutter'
  ])</textarea>
```